# Ошибка при компиляции: Undefined first referenced symbol

Tags: g++, map-reduce, solaris, c++, компиляция

```
using namespace std;

#include "hadoop/Pipes.hh"
#include "hadoop/TemplateFactory.hh"
#include "hadoop/StringUtils.hh"
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include "traverser.h"

class IndexMap:public HadoopPipes::Mapper {
  public:IndexMap(HadoopPipes::TaskContext & context) { } 
    void map(HadoopPipes::MapContext & context) {
        std::vector<std::string> paths = HadoopUtils::splitString(context.getInputValue(), "rn");
        int k = 4;
        int l = 0;
        string concatpaths[k];
        if (paths.size() % k == 0) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                concatpaths[i] = paths[l];
                l = l + paths.size() / k;
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() / k; ++j) {
                    concatpaths[i] = +" " + paths[i * paths.size() / k + j];
                }
            }
        } else {
            l = 0;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                concatpaths[i] = paths[l];
                l = l + paths.size() / (k - 1);
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; ++i) {
                for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() / (k - 1); ++j) {
                    concatpaths[i] = +" " + paths[i * paths.size() / (k - 1) + j];
                }
            }
            for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() - paths.size() / (k - 1) * (k - 1); ++j) {
                concatpaths[k - 1] = +" " + paths[(k - 1) * paths.size() / (k - 1) + j];
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                context.emit(concatpaths[i], "0");
            }
        }
    }
};

class IndexReduce:public HadoopPipes::Reducer {
  public:
    IndexReduce(HadoopPipes::TaskContext & context) { } 
    void reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext & context) {
        int count;
        PGconn *conn;
        conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.143.93 port=5432 connect_timeout=5 dbname=search1 user=postgres password=postgres");
        if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
            puts("Не удается подключиться к базе данных");
            exit(0);
        }
        std::vector<std::string> processedpaths = HadoopUtils::splitString(context.getInputValue(), " ");
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < processedpaths.size(); ++i) {
            count = Traverser(processedpaths[i].c_str());
        }
        context.emit(processedpaths[processedpaths.size() - 1], HadoopUtils::toString(count));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::TemplateFactory<IndexMap, IndexReduce> ());
}
```

Решил откомпилировать программу согласно [Hadoop Tutorial 2.2 -- Running C++ Programs on Hadoop](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop). Создал следующий Makefile

```
CC = g++
HADOOP_INSTALL = /export/hadoop-1.0.1
PLATFORM = Linux-i386-32
CPPFLAGS = -m32 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/include

parindex: hadoopc++.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/lib -lhadooppipes \
    -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@
```

Ввел команду `make parindex` и получил следующую ошибку:

> `g++ -m32
> -I/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/include
> -Wall -L/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib
> -lhadooppipes \
>     -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o parindex
>     Undefined first referenced symbol in file main /usr/lib/crt1.o
>     ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to parindex
>     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>     *** Error code 1
>     make: Fatal error: Command failed for target`parindex'`

Comment: @ivan31, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646457/undefined-reference-to-main-error-in-crt1-o-function-start

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, а можно подробнее (я не очень хорошо владею английским).

Comment: Да попробуйте Вы команду сборки в одну строку уместить!

Comment: @mikillskeg,  я заменил $< на $^ и получил другую ошибку
 
>`ld: fatal: file /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/crtbegin.o; section [7].eh_frame and file /export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib/libhadooppipes.a(HadoopPipes.o); section [1269].eh_frame have incompatibile attributes and cannot be merged into a single output section
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `parindex'`

Answer (score 1):

[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31), для начала попробуйте выполнить

```
g++ -m32 -I/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/include -L/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -o parindex hadoopc++.cpp
```

И посмотрите, что получится. Если нормально вернитесь к Makefile

Основные символы подстановок в нем:

```
@$ target
@^ all right part
@? only new in right part
@< first name from right part
```

Comment: Undefined   first referenced
 symbol         in file
PQconnectdb                         /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
Traverser(char const*)              /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
PQstatus                            /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::Factory const&) /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
HadoopUtils::toString(int)          /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
HadoopUtils::splitString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to parindex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Ivan31, вроде бы (в другом Вашем вопросе) выяснили, что проблема похоже в несовместимости библиотеки из

    /export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib

с солярисом.