# Не видна функция при сборке: Undefined first referenced symbol

Tags: g++, map-reduce, solaris, компиляция, c++

При компиляции hadoop-программы, указанной в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141156/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-undefined-first-referenced-symbol) с помощью команды

```
g++ /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++ -Iinstall/include -Linstall/lib -lhadooputils -lhadooppipes -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -lsocket -lnsl -lpq -lsrc -o parindex.
```

В результате выдало ошибку

> `Undefined first referenced symbol in file Traverser(char const*) /var/tmp//ccdqaaGF.o 
>       ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to parindex
>
>       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Я подключал ключом `-lsrc` библиотеку `libsrc.a`, которая была сделана из файлов `avl_tree.c, buf_read.c, db_prep.c, file_process.c, global_header.c, traverser.c`.

Привожу текст файла `traverser.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <pwd.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <time.h>  

#include "include/traverser.h"  

const char * pParams[] = {
    "ServerIP",
    "ServerPort",
    "DBName",
    "Login",
    "Password",
    NULL
};

char sIP[15];
char sPort[5];
char sDBName[64];
char sLogin[64];
char sPassword[64];
char sConnInfo[512];
int nClock = 0;

long int
TraverseFiles(PGconn *pConn, const char * sDir);
long int
TraverseDirs(PGconn *pConn, const char * sDir);

long int
CheckParam(const char * sParam)
{
    long int i = 0;

    for (; pParams[i]; ++i)
        if (!strcmp(sParam, pParams[i]))
            return i;

    return -1;
}

long int
Configure(const char * sConfig)
{
    char sParam[64];
    long int nParamID;
    long int ret = 0;;
    char sValue[64];
    char sError[512];
    FILE * pConfig = fopen(sConfig, "r");

    for (;;) {
        memset(sParam, 0, 64);
        fscanf(pConfig, "%64[^=]=", sParam);

        if (!sParam[0])
            break;

        nParamID = CheckParam(sParam);

        if (nParamID == -1) {
            sprintf(sError, "Config error : %512s symbol not found\n");
            AddErrorToLog(sError);
            ret = 1;
            break;
        }

        switch (nParamID) {
        case 0: 
            fscanf(pConfig, "%15[^\n]\n", sIP);
            break;
        case 1:
            fscanf(pConfig, "%5[^\n]\n", sPort);
            break;
        case 2:
            fscanf(pConfig, "%64[^\n]\n", sDBName);
            break;
        case 3:
            fscanf(pConfig, "%64[^\n]\n", sLogin);
            break;
        case 4:
            fscanf(pConfig, "%64[^\n]\n", sPassword);
            break;
        default:
            AddErrorToLog("+++");
            break;
        }

    }

    fclose(pConfig);

    return 0;
}

long int
_Traverser(PGconn * pConn, const char * sTraversingRoot)
{
    return TraverseFiles(pConn, sTraversingRoot) + TraverseDirs(pConn, sTraversingRoot);
}

void
GetActualPath(char * sActualPath, const char * sTraversingRoot)
{
    int p, l = 1, n = 0;
    char c;

    sActualPath[0] = '\0';

    if (sTraversingRoot[0] != '/') {
        getcwd(sActualPath, 512);
        strcat(sActualPath, "/");
    }

    strcat(sActualPath, sTraversingRoot);

    for (;;) {
        c = sActualPath[l];
        switch(c) {
        case '.': 
            ++n;
            break;
        case '\0':
        case '/':
            if (n == 0) {
                strcpy(sActualPath + l - 1, sActualPath + l);
                --l;
            }
            if (n == 1) {
                p = l--;
                while (sActualPath[l--] != '/') {}
                strcpy(sActualPath + ++l, sActualPath + p);
            }
            if (n == 2) {
                p = l;
                l -= 4;
                if (l < 0) {
                    c = '\0';
                    sActualPath[0] = '\0';
                    break;
                }
                while (sActualPath[l--] != '/') {}
                strcpy(sActualPath + ++l, sActualPath + p);
            }
            n = 0;
            break;
        default:
            n = -1000;
        }
        ++l;
        if (c == '\0')
            break;
    }
}

long int
Traverser(const char * sTraversingRoot) 
{
    long int nCount;
    struct stat rStatBuf;
    time_t nTime;
    char sActualPath[512];
    PGconn *pConn;

    // Open DB connection
    sprintf(sConnInfo, 
        "hostaddr=%s port=%s connect_timeout=50 dbname=%s user=%s password=%s",
        sIP, sPort, sDBName, sLogin, sPassword);
    pConn = PQconnectdb(sConnInfo);
    if (PQstatus(pConn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        AddErrorToLog("No connect\n");
        return 0;
    }

    GetActualPath(sActualPath, sTraversingRoot);

    stat(sActualPath, &rStatBuf);

    if (nClock)
        nTime = time(NULL);

    if(S_ISREG(rStatBuf.st_mode)) {
        nCount = 1;
        ProcessFile(pConn, sActualPath);
    }

    if(S_ISDIR(rStatBuf.st_mode)) {
        nCount = _Traverser(pConn, sActualPath);
    }

    if (nClock)
        fprintf(stdout, "Total time : %u second(s)\n", time(NULL) - nTime);
    // Close DB connection
    PQfinish(pConn);

    return nCount;
}

// Open DB connection and get all files to process
long int
TraverseFiles(PGconn *pConn, const char * sDir)
{
    long int nCount = 0;
    DIR * pDir;
    struct dirent *pDirEntry;
    struct stat rStatBuf;

    // Open directory
    if ((pDir = opendir(sDir)) == NULL) {
        long int nError = errno;
        AddErrorToLog("\nTraverse_file Error:");
        AddErrorToLog(sDir);
        AddErrorToLog("Directory can not be opened");
        AddErrorToLog(strerror(nError));
        return 0;
    }

    // Traverse it
    char sTempDir[512];
    while (pDirEntry = readdir(pDir)) {
        snprintf (sTempDir, sizeof(sTempDir), "%s/%s", sDir, pDirEntry->d_name);
        stat(sTempDir, &rStatBuf);
        if (S_ISREG(rStatBuf.st_mode)) {
            if (ProcessFile(pConn, sTempDir))
                nCount++;
        }
    }

    // And close
    closedir(pDir);

    return nCount;
}

long int
TraverseDirs(PGconn *pConn, const char * sDir)
{
    long int nCount = 0;
    DIR * pDir;
    struct dirent *pDirEntry;
    struct stat rStatBuf;

    // Open directory
    if ((pDir = opendir(sDir)) == NULL) {
        long int nError = errno;
        AddErrorToLog("\nTraverse_dirs Error:");
        AddErrorToLog(sDir);
        AddErrorToLog("Directory can not be opened");
        AddErrorToLog(strerror(nError));
        return 0;
    }

    // Traverse it
    char sTempDir[512];
    while (pDirEntry = readdir(pDir))
        // . and .. is special dirs that we should not process
        if ((strcmp(".", pDirEntry->d_name)) && strcmp("..", pDirEntry->d_name)) {
            snprintf (sTempDir, sizeof(sTempDir), "%s/%s", sDir, pDirEntry->d_name);
            stat(sTempDir, &rStatBuf);
            if (S_ISDIR(rStatBuf.st_mode)) {
                nCount += _Traverser(pConn, sTempDir);
            }
        }

    // And close
    closedir(pDir);
    return nCount;
}
```

Привожу код traverser.h

```
#ifndef _TRAVERSER_H_  
#define _TRAVERSER_H_
#include "global_header.h"  
#include "file_process.h"  

// Recurent traverse of file system tree with sTraversingRoot as a root  
long int  
Traverser(const char * sTraversingRoot);  

long int  
Configure(const char * sConfig);  

#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было в исходник hadoop-программы добавить

```
extern "C"  
{  
    #include "traverser.h"  
}
```

Comment: @ivan31, Вы в своих вопросах выдавайте побольше информации, относящейся к делу.

В данном случае, как делали библиотеку. Ведь из t.c можно получить t.o, как
gcc -c t.c, так и g++ -c t.c, но это будут разные .o